# having issues with cached table viewcells

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have the following code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell

    cell.cellIndex = indexPath
    cell.dataSource = self
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    var books = [Book]();

    let count = self.enterpriseBooks.count;
    if count > 0 && indexPath.section < self.enterpriseBooks_2.count {
        books = self.enterpriseBooks_2[indexPath.section]!;
    }

    if (indexPath.section == (count)) {
        books = nytbooks;
    } else if (indexPath.section == (count + 1)) {
        books = trendingbooks;
    } else if (indexPath.section == (count + 2)) {
        books = newbooks
    }

    if (books.count > 0) {
        if (cell.collectionView === nil) {
            cell.addCollectionView();
            cell.collectionView.tag = 124;
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

// BookTableViewCell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! BookCollectionViewCell

    self.dataSource?.getData(cell: self)

    let books = self.books
    let book = books?[indexPath.row]

    if book != nil {
        cell.label.text = book?.title
        cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: book?.image as! String), placeholderImage: nil)
    }

    return cell
}

func addCollectionView () {
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: self.frame.height)

    //You can also provide estimated Height and Width
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: self.frame.height)

    //For Setting the Spacing between cells
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 25
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20

    let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"
    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 10,
                                                         y: 0,
                                                         width: self.frame.width,
                                                         height: self.frame.height),
                                           collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.register(BookCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.addSubview(collectionView)
}
```

The issue is I'm running into caching issues where content in a table view cell or collection view cell are overlapping with each other. Can anyone please help?

The above content shows images horizontally aligned into three rows using collection views for each.